# Bootstrap Carousel Displaying All Slides at Once

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

As a beginner developer, I hope my problem's solution is not too obvious :-P
I have already checked several questions in stackoverflow, read Bootstrap documentation, changed many properties and class names in my code. Bootstrap script CDN are in the bottom of html body.

Right now, all the slides are being shown at once, and when I click the control buttons, the images seem to cycle, but the slides keep stacked one over the other.

Edit - more details: i did try the classes "carousel-item" (instead of just "item") and "w-100" and "d-block", but they don't seem to have any effect.
Updated the code to reflect these classes as I added them.

```
<!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="product-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-slide carousel-item active">
                <img class="carousel-image d-block w-100" src="image.jpg" alt="">
                <h3 class="carousel-text">Carousel text over here!
                    <button href="#" class=""></button></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-slide">
                <img class="carousel-image d-block w-100" src="img.jpg" alt="">
                <h3 class="carousel-text">Carousel text over here!
                    <button href="#" class=""></button>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-slide">
                <img class="carousel-image d-block w-100" src="img.jpg" alt="">
                <h3 class="carousel-text">Carousel text over here!
                    <button href="#" class=""> </button>
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel Controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#product-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <svg width="22" height="43" viewBox="0 0 22 43" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M1.68334e-06 23.7448L2.07584e-06 19.2552L22 0L22 7.59695L9.77822 21.4997L22 35.4031L22 43L1.68334e-06 23.7448Z" fill="white" />
            </svg>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#product-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <svg class="carousel-next-button" aria-hidden="true" width="22" height="43" viewBox="0 0 22 43" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M22 19.2552V23.7448L0 43V35.4031L12.2218 21.5003L0 7.59695V0L22 19.2552Z" fill="white" />
            </svg>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Relevant CSS looks like this:

```
/* Products Carousel */
.carousel-inner {
    background-color: #E48500;
    display: flex;
    padding: 8%;
    align-items: center;
}

.carousel-slide {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
}

.carousel-image {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-image {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 24px;
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

.carousel-text {
    color: #221110;
    font-size: 2.33rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    background-color: #D14D13;
    margin: auto 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 170px;
    width: 51px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the codepen link for the solution - [Codepen solution link](https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/PoNvmKL)
You have missed using the correct class name "carousal-item" for the div inside "carousel-inner". This is the correct structure -

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your help, AKNair. After reading your answer and how you made it work on Codepen with only a few changes, I realized my problem were the images, since they were not included in my question. Apparently "display: flex" is incompatible with the carousel.

All I had to do was remove the flex related properties.